# Twilio SMS API Auth Exception with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twilio, twilio-api

I'm attempting to send an SMS through Twilio after I come to a specific controller with localhost. I'm receiving the following exception: "The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure." The exception is highlighted on "var message = ..."

Here is the controller:

```
SMS_Job sms = new SMS_Job();

public ActionResult 
{
    sms.SendMessage();

    return View();
}
```

Here is the custom class with Twilio:

```
public class SMS_Job
{
    string _twilioAccountSID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAccountSID"];
    string _twilioAuthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwilioAuthToken"];


    public void SendMessage()
    {
        string accountSid = _twilioAccountSID;
        string authToken = _twilioAuthToken;
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);


        var message = MessageResource.Create (
            to: new PhoneNumber("+XXXXXXXXXXX"),
            from: new PhoneNumber("+XXXXXXXXXXX"),
            body: "Hello Twilio"
        );
        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
    }
}
```

I tried to enable SSL on my localhost but perhaps it wasn't configured properly? Am I not using the API is the correct manner?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm no C# developer I'm afraid. However, I've taken a look around the web and it appears that [this article by Jeff Sanders](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/09/16/troubleshooting-asp-net-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation-procedure/) has the most complete and helpful advice on fixing your issue.